# Extend a model class by a variable

Tags: angularjs, angular, select

I have a model class named user :

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public UserId?: number,
    public Name?: string,
    public Password?: string,
    public IsActive?: boolean,
    public RoleId?: number
   ) {
}
```

}

For ng2-select component, I need these properties : text and id.

Now when I set them via

```
this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(
          data => this.users = data,
          err => this.error(err));
```

there are no text and id property.

Is there a method where I can set these properties on initialization.

I dont wan't to write everytime a workaround with :

```
data.forEach(g =>
    {
      g.text = g.Name;
      g.id = g.Id;
    });

this.users = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are not typing your array `users` to your `User` class anyway in the above code snippet, so you could introduce another class and where you handle this assignment in `map`.

```
export class UserSelect {
  constructor(
    public text: string,
    public id: number
   ) {
}
```

and in your Service:

```
getAllUsers() {
  return this.http......
    .map(res => res.json().map(x => new UserSelect(x.Name, x.Id)))
}
```

and then you just subscribe normally

```
this.userService.getAllUsers()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.users = data;
  })
```

Then you would have an Array of type `UserSelect` which has the proper properties you need :) Of course you can extend this and include any properties you need, keeping in mind that not knowing to which extent you are using the `users` array and if you are needing the other properties, or original properties...